# Using assignment pattern for union inside a struct in SystemVerilog

Tags: verilog, verification, system-verilog, hdl

This is an example for illustration. In SystemVerilog, it has array assignment pattern and struct assignment pattern syntax. No matter the union construct here is packed or unpacked, whether it is synthesizable or not, is it a valid usage for assignment pattern? If yes, what value should be for union `x`?

```
typedef struct {
  int a;
  byte b;
  union packed {
      int c;
      bit [31:0] d;
  } x;
} S;

module top (s);
  output S s;
  assign s = '{int:2, default:1};
endmodule
```

If no, is it means I have to specify the initial value each field by field for the unpacked structure?

```
initial begin
  s.a = 2;
  s.b = 1;
  s.x.c = 2;
end
```

Comment: The initial value can also be specified like this: `assign s = '{int:2, default:1, x: 2}` – at least in VCS, Modelsim & Incisive this syntax works.

Answer (score 2):

I modified your code little bit to print the assigned values.

```
typedef struct {
  int a;        
  byte b;       
  union packed {
      int c;
      bit [31:0] d;
  } x; 
} S;

module top (s);
  output S s;
  assign s = '{int:2, default:1};

  initial begin
    #10
        $display ("s.a = %d, s.b = %h, s.x.c = %d, s.x.d = %h", s.a, s.b, s.x.c, s.x.d);
  end 
endmodule
```

Following is the result from ncsim:

```
s.a =           2, s.b = 01, s.x.c =           1, s.x.d = 00000001
```

And from vcs:

```
s.a =           2, s.b = 01, s.x.c =           1, s.x.d = 00000001
```

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Run simulator is always doable to see results, but it could lead to implementation dependent cuz I think there is something the LRM does not fully described. In LRM, the `type:` specifier and `default:` specifier have to apply to sub-array elements or every field of a structure either the type matches for `type:` or `default:` values. However, for the `union` type, it represents either `int` or `bit vector`. So it could apply 2 to `int` type and also apply 1 to the `bit vector` type. But it's a conflict to assign different values for `c` or `d` at the same time using assignment patterns.

Comment: So if I want to assign 2 to the `int` type of `union x`, I have still use sub-field name-based assignment to safely give the specified value to them explicitly to save time for debugging when other tools might have different implementation/interpretation of such syntax. So if I want to assign 2 to the `int` type of `union x`, I have still use sub-field name-based assignment to safely give the specified value to them explicitly to save time for debugging when other tools might have different implementation/interpretation of such syntax.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this modified example:

```
typedef bit [31:0] Word;
typedef struct {
  int a;
  byte b;
  union packed {
      int c;
      Word d;
  } x;
  union packed {
      Word d;
      int c;
  } y;
} S;

module top (s);
  output S s;
  assign s = '{ int:2, Word:3, default:1 };

  initial begin
    #10
        $display ("s.a = %d, s.b = %h, s.x.c = %d, s.x.d = %h s.y.d = %h s.y.c = %d",
                  s.a, s.b, s.x.c, s.x.d, s.y.d, s.y.c);
  end 
endmodule
```

Modelsim gives this output:

```
s.a =           2, s.b = 01, s.x.c =           3, s.x.d = 00000003 s.y.d = 00000002 s.y.c =           2
```

whereas VCS gives this output:

```
s.a =           2, s.b = 01, s.x.c =           3, s.x.d = 00000003 s.y.d = 00000003 s.y.c =           3
```

This shows that simulators treat such code the way they want and there is no standard behaviour to be expected.

The following syntax would be safer to use:

```
assign s = '{ int:2, default:1, x:3, y:4 };
```

With this both Modelsim & VCS give:

```
s.a =           2, s.b = 01, s.x.c =           3, s.x.d = 00000003 s.y.d = 00000004 s.y.c =           4
```

Comment: @jclin I tried `assign s = '{ int:2, default:1, x:'{ c:3 }, y:'{ d:4 };` but VCS said `Member "d" of the variable "s" of type "packed union" has not been assigned a value` & a similar message for `s.y.c`. However, both that syntax and this one: `assign s = '{int:2, default:1, x:'{ c:3, d:3 }, y:'{ c:4, d:4 }};` do not work with Modelsim which says `Illegal assignment of structure literals to union.`

Answer (score 0):

I think identifying union members by type instead of name is an anti-pattern, but YMMV.  I had the same question, and I think the answer is "you can't."

It might clarify the issue if the union members are themselves packed structs:

```
module tb();

typedef struct packed {
  logic [7:0] b1;
  logic [7:0] b0;
} two_bytes_t;

typedef struct packed {
  logic [3:0] n3;
  logic [3:0] n2;
  logic [3:0] n1;
  logic [3:0] n0;
} four_nibbles_t;

typedef union packed {
  two_bytes_t two_bytes;
  four_nibbles_t four_nibbles;
} my_union_t;

my_union_t my_union;

typedef struct packed {
  logic [7:0] a;
  my_union_t u;
} my_struct_t;

my_struct_t my_struct;

initial begin
  my_union.two_bytes = '{b0: 1, b1: 2};
  my_union.four_nibbles = '{n0: 1, n1: 1, n2: 3, n3: 4};
  $display("%p", my_union);

`ifdef UNDEFINED
  // this doesn't work:
  //
  my_struct = '{
    u.two_bytes: '{b0: 3, b1: 4},
    default: '0
  };
  // produces:
  //     u.two_bytes: '{b0: 3, b1: 4},
  //               |
  // xmelab: *E,CUVUNF (./foo.sv,35|14): Hierarchical name component lookup failed for 'u' at 'tb'.
  //     u.two_bytes: '{b0: 3, b1: 4},
  //     |
  // xmelab: *E,URCEN (./foo.sv,35|4): Unresolved constant expression VST_AP_ITEM.
`endif
  // this works:
  my_struct = '0;
  my_struct.u.two_bytes = '{b0: 1, b1: 2};
  $display("%p", my_struct);
end

endmodule : tb
```